# Have web app do tasks when it is not opened by a user

Tags: web-services, web-applications

I'm a semi-experienced developer but a total noob to writing web apps. My question is: would it be possible to have a web app perform some sort of task while it is not opened by any user? For my purposes, I want it to send out text messages to users based on provided phone numbers, but this task must perform when the app is not opened by the user. At a high level, how exactly would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level: The web server on which the application is being hosted will need to run, regardless of user activity. Therefore, it is plausible to also run either a service or scheduled job from this server, or to host a separate application that runs at a fixed interval.  That is the high level answer at least :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, and yes. Depends on your definition of "web server".

If you're talking about the service (e.g. Apache) then no. If you're just talking about the server that your web server is on then yes.

Basically you will need a companion app that runs as a service on the parent OS. It can be written in a language of your choice. The key is in getting your web app and companion app communicating.

The simplest way is to have your web app and companion app use a shared database like MySQL or Mongo. If you need real time communication between your app's users and the companion app you may want to investigate using a messaging service like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easily possible, but it depends on your environment.

As Example:
When using Java/[Tomcat/Jetty/or whatever] you could create an Servlet which is automatically loaded when your "App" is being loaded.
You can put your "tasks-code" into this servlets init-Method.

Edit:
in web.xml you can configure, which of your servlets should be automatically loaded.